# Looping through table and changing <tr> background depending on which checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I have a table with table rows, which contain 2 checkboxes in them, one is under the class of `student_late`, and the other is under the class of `student_present`.

I want it to do the following:

If the `student_present` checkbox only is checked, make the tablerow green by adding the class "success".

If the `student_present` checkbox is checked as well as the `student_late` checkbox, make the tablerow yellow by adding the class "info".

If no checkbox is checked, make the tablerow red by adding the class "danger".

This is my current CoffeScript:

```
$(document).ready ->
  return $("tr .student_present").each(->
    if @checked
      $(this).closest("tr").addClass "success"
    else
      $(this).closest("tr").addClass "danger"
  )
  $("tr .student_late").each ->
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass "info"  if @checked
```

Or for those who prefer JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("tr .student_present").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      return $(this).closest("tr").addClass("success");
    } else {
      return $(this).closest("tr").addClass("danger");
    }
  });
      return $("tr .student_late").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
      return $(this).closest("tr").addClass("info");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you'll have to add some example markup to this ?

Comment: You have two return statements in your JS ready function. That could be causing some issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use return for document ready. Here is the code that you could use.

```
$(function() {
    $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
       var $row = $(this);
       var late = $row.find('.student_late')[0].checked;
       var present = $row.find('.student_present')[0].checked;
        if(present && !late) {
            $row.addClass('success');
        } else if(present && late) {
            $row.addClass('info');    
        } else if(!present && !late) {
            $row.addClass('danger');    
        }
    });
});
```

$(function() is just a shorthand for $(document).ready(function() . Here is JSfiddle of the code working. http://jsfiddle.net/5DUwr/

If you want it to update when you click a checkbox. Use this code

```
$(function() {
    $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
       var $row = $(this);
       updateRow($row);
    });

    $('table tbody tr input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
       var $row = $(this).parents('tr');
       updateRow($row);
    });
});

function updateRow($row) {
       $row.removeClass('success danger info');
       var late = $row.find('.student_late')[0].checked;
       var present = $row.find('.student_present')[0].checked;
        if(present && !late) {
            $row.addClass('success');
        } else if(present && late) {
            $row.addClass('info');    
        } else if(!present && !late) {
            $row.addClass('danger');    
        }   
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5DUwr/4/

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what the problem is here, I've just replicated your code and it seems to work fine (obviously I don't have your HTML, though)... http://jsfiddle.net/VWcXW/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="student_present"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="student_present" checked="checked"></input></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("tr .student_present").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      return $(this).closest("tr").addClass("success");
    } else {
      return $(this).closest("tr").addClass("error");
    }
  });
      return $("tr .student_late").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
               return $(this).closest("tr").addClass("info");
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: Tried your code, but except for two checkboxes which don't do anything when checked, I can't see anything else

Comment: Oh, so you're wanting checked events? You made absolutely no mention of that in your question.

Comment: Oh, no sorry I don't need it to change when the actual event is called. Just when the checkbox is already checked

Comment: On that fiddle, one is already checked, and the class of the parent <tr> on that is "success", the <tr> of the one that isn't checked is "error". http://jsfiddle.net/VWcXW/1/ for the colours.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ba5qg/

I mean, it's executed once !
It's not binding click event to change the background-color...
That you could change with:

```
$("tr .student_present").on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('success');
        [...]
    }
});
```

Fiddle code:
HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='student_present' class='student_present' checked /></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='student_late' class='student_late' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='student_present' class='student_present' /></td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='student_late' class='student_late' checked /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.success {
    background: green;
}

.error {
    background: red;
}

.info {
    background: yellow;
}
```

JS
You can remove your return statement here !

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr .student_present").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            return $(this).closest("tr").addClass("success");
        } else {
            return $(this).closest("tr").addClass("error");
        }
    });
    $("tr .student_late").each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            return $(this).closest("tr").addClass("info");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add unique ids for your checkboxes i.e. 'chk_001' and eqivalent numbers in the ids of the tr/td tags.
Then looping through the checkboxes your can grab the rows you want to change.
When you use the same numbers in the tr/td ids (like tr_001 or td_001) you can set the desired classes/styles using getElementById wherever you find the checkbox checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be achieved easier([Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtbnZ/9/)):

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="student_present" type="checkbox" checked="checked">Present</td>
        <td><input class="student_late" type="checkbox">Late</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><input class="student_present" type="checkbox">Present</td>
        <td><input class="student_late" type="checkbox" checked="checked">Late</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.success {
    background: green;
}

.error {
    background: red;
}

.info{
    background: yellow;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".student_present").closest('tr').addClass('error');
    $(".student_present:checked").closest('tr').toggleClass('success error');
    $(".student_late:checked").closest('tr').addClass(function() {
        if($('.student_present', $(this).closest('tr')).is(':checked')) return 'info';
        else return '';
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem with your answer is that the background turns yellow even if only the late checkbox is checked. But the late checkbox can only be checked if the present checkbox is already checked

Comment: Ah missed that, I'll fix it.